# Close v-navigation-drawer from parent component when clicking outside

Tags: vue.js

I have a navigation drawer that is its own component. The toggling of visibility is controlled from the parent component by passing a prop that is assigned as the v-model of the v-navigation-drawer. I then emit an event form child to update the prop from the parent. That works fine. However, when clicking from outside, the navigation drawer doesn't close. I came up with the solution below to manually close the navigation drawer on outside click. I added a condition so that it only responds when the target is the overlay. Is there a better way of handling this so that the navigation-drawer closes when clicking only on the overlay and not on other elements from the parent?

```
//DrawerComponent.vue

  <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="isDrawerShowing"
      temporary
      fixed
      :width=width
      :height="height"
      right
      stateless
      v-click-outside="hideDrawer"
  ></v-navigation-drawer>
```

```
  hideDrawer(e) {
      if(e.target.className === "v-overlay__scrim") {
        this.$emit('hide-drawer',false);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the only good solution until now! Thank you @D'Mar